# "attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope" - Error in Drupal with Google Graph api

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, google-visualization

I'm trying to include the Google graph api in my Drupal 7 module (not the google graph module). But when I try to call upon the service I get:

- "attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope" - error in
  Firefox.
- "Could not send response: Cannot send a response more than once per
  chrome.extension.onRequest listener per document" -error in Chrome.

Code is as follows:

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
        // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
        // draws it.
        function drawChart() {

          // Create the data table.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
          data.addRows([
            ['Mushrooms', 3],
            ['Onions', 1],
            ['Olives', 1],
            ['Zucchini', 1],
            ['Pepperoni', 2]
          ]);

          // Set chart options
          var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                         'width':400,
                         'height':300};

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        alert("test");
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

What can I do to get this to work ?
-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

The `google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});` line should be called first, just after `(function ($) {`. so the solution is :

```
(function ($) {
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
        // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
        // draws it.
        function drawChart() {

          // Create the data table.
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
          data.addRows([
            ['Mushrooms', 3],
            ['Onions', 1],
            ['Olives', 1],
            ['Zucchini', 1],
            ['Pepperoni', 2]
          ]);

          // Set chart options
          var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                         'width':400,
                         'height':300};

          // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
          var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        alert("test");
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```